# Why can't I execute some commands from Process?

Tags: python, dart, rust

In python, I can execute a shell script/command by doing this.

```py
import os

os.system('echo hello')
```

This code will yield the expected output, `hello` from stdout, and exit code of 0. But when I try to execute commands from rust or dart, commands like `echo` and `ls` won't work.

```rust
// rust
Command::new("echo")
        .arg("hello")
        .spawn()
        .expect("echo command failed to start");
```

```dart
// dart
await Process.run('echo', ['hello'])
```

Both of these will yield binary file/command not found errors. Why is that? I am simply looking for an equivalent of python's `system` function in both of these languages.

I don't think it is because of the OS used. Because even if `ls` don't wok on windows, `echo` should. I tested both `dir` and `ls` because I was worried it is about OS, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `echo` is not a program found on the computer, it is a shell command. `Command::new` takes in an executable to run as a sub-process.

If you are on windows you can use

```
Command::new("cmd")
    .args(&["/C", "echo hello!"])
    .spawn()
    .expect("echo command failed to start");
```

to run the `CMD` program and `/C` to pass in a command, in this case `echo`.

On linux you can use the `bash` executable.

```
Command::new("bash")
    .args(&["-c", "echo hello"])
    .spawn()
    .expect("echo command failed to start");
```

[See the rust docs for std::process::Command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html)

Comment: Side note: Linux systems usually have `/bin/echo`, but it's not used because the shell builtin overrides it.

Comment: Is there any way to get current shell name, since I don't want to override the current shell with bash or cmd. The user might be using a different shell than these.

Comment: @FrencoJobs You can see in the [docs for system(3) on linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), what i assume python uses, that it calls `/bin/sh`. That might be your best option. You can call `system(3)` directly with the [libc crate](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.71/libc/fn.system.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `runInShell` param to true, like:

```dart
  var r = await Process.run('echo', ['hello'], runInShell: true);
  print(r.stdout); //Prints 'hello'
```

From the [dart api](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/Process/run.html)

> If runInShell is true, the process will be spawned through a system shell. On Linux and OS X, /bin/sh is used, while %WINDIR%\system32\cmd.exe is used on Windows.

Comment: This bring us to my old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171994/how-to-get-current-shell-in-dart. I'm using PowerShell and ls command should be working, if `runInShell` option really does what it should. But since cmd is used for windows, the `ls` command won't work when it should.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to get the default shell on windows (I don't even know how to set it), if you want to run some command in the powershell only you can check this https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36175